# How to retrieve parentId when only know childId in Firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, cloud

I'm new to js and Firebase cloud functions. I have a basic data structure in Firebase with a parent node each for 'posts' and 'comments', which basically looks like this:

'posts' > userId > postId

'comments' > postId > commentId

I have a method to observe whenever there is a new comment which gives me the postId and the commentId. The method looks like this:

```
exports.observeComment = functions.database.ref('/comments/{postId}/{commentId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  var postId = context.params.postId;
  var commentId = context.params.commentId;
  console.log('LOGGER --- New comment, postId: ' + postId + ' , commentId: ' + commentId);


  return admin.database().ref().child('/posts/').once('value', function(snapshot) {

    //Get userId

  })
})
```

I now want to retrieve the userId for the postId - how would I go about doing that?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
return admin.database().ref().child('/posts/').orderByChild('postId').equalTo(postId).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    //Get userId
    snapshot.forEach((function(child) { console.log(child.userId) });
});
```